# Zero Locus of a Rational Function on an Affine Variety is Zariski-Closed

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-geometry

**Set-up.** Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.

Let $V\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ be an irreducible Zariski-closed subset.

Let $f$ be a rational function on $V$ (in other words, let $f$ be an element of $k(V)$).

**Question.** I want to show that the set
$$W:=\{P \in V \, : \, f \text{ is regular at } P \;\text{ and }\; f(P)=0\}$$
is a Zariski-closed subset of $V.$

**Attempt.** We can write $f=F/G\,$ for some $F,G \in k[V].$

Then, for any $P \in V$ at which $f$ is regular, we have
$$f(P)=0 \Leftrightarrow F(P)=0$$
and so $W=\mathbb{V}(F),$ the zero locus of $F$ in $V,$ which is Zariski-closed by definition.

---

**EDIT.** It has been pointed out below that the correct statement is that

"$W$ is a Zariski-closed subset, not of $V,\,$ but of $\;\mathrm{dom}(f):=\{P \in V \, : \, f \text{ is regular at } P\}$".

Comment: It is a Zariski-closed subset not of $V$ but of "$V$ minus the poles of $f$" (the zeros of $G$) try with $f = \frac{x}{y} \in k(x,y) =k(\Bbb{A}^2)$ then $W =(0,\overline{k}^*)$ whose closure is $(0,\overline{k})$ (it is for the same reason that there are missing points on the affine part of a projective variety).

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! So I wanted to solve this in order to solve another problem: "Let $f$ be a rational function on $V$ and let $U=\{P \in V \, : \, f \text{ is defined at } P\}.$ Then $f$ defines a function on $U.$ Prove that this function uniquely determines $f.$"

Comment: But now (after your correction) I can't use the density argument that I wanted to use... Any suggestions? I can be more precise if that would be useful :) Also, I should have said that I'm taking $k$ algebraically closed (for what it's worth).

Comment: If it doesn't define $f$ uniquely there are two extensions of it thus a rational function which vanishes on $U$ but not on $V-U$

Comment: But why can't that happen? I think this is the exact point at which I'm stuck. I know that, as a non-empty open subset of an irreducible space, the set $U$ is dense in $V.$

Comment: It can't happen because $V$ is irreducible : for any sub-algebraic set $S$, either $S$ is dense or $V-S$ is dense, because otherwise we would have $V = \overline{S}\cup \overline{V-S}$  with both smaller than $V$. The definition of $\overline{S}$ is the intersection of the zeros of all the functions regular on $V$ and vanishing on $S$